# Why the copy constructor is called

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-keyword

I cannot  undestand why a copy constructor is called instead of a compile error.

I  have declare two classes A B , which are independent . A is not based/derived of B. The only connection between them is that in B I use an operator that converts B to A
I have defined an operator = that gets as an argument a  const reference of B. 
In main  I have written the following instnace of B = instance of A. I expect that a compile error will be generated. But the operator = is called

```
class A {};

class B {
public:
    // conversion from A (constructor):
    B()
    {

        cout << "1." << endl;
    }
    B(const A& x)
    {
        cout << "4." << endl;
    }
    // conversion from A (assignment):
    B& operator= (const B& x)
    {
        cout << "3." << endl;
        return *this;
    }
    // conversion to A (type-cast operator)
    operator A() {
        cout << "2." << endl;
        return A();
    }
};

int main()
{
    A foo;
    B bar;    // calls constructor
    bar = foo;      // calls assignment
                    //foo = bar;      // calls type-cast operator
    char c;
    c = getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I expect compile error. But the following sequence is printed
1 4 3 .
I hardly undestand how the copy constructor is called and why the operator = does not generate problem

Thank you

Comment: It's unclear to me why you think an error should be generated. What kind of error? What do you think is wrong with the program?

Comment: I expect the following compile error  will  be generated                                         39:6: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'B' and 'A')
39:6: note: candidate is:
23:5: note: B& B::operator=(const B&)
23:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'A' to 'const B&'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I expect the following compile error will be generated
>
> ```
> no match for 'operator=' ... note: no known conversion for argument 1 from 'A' to 'const B&'
> ```

There is no reason to expect such error, because there **is** a known conversion from `A` to `const B&`. `B` has a converting constructor for `A`:

> ```
> B(const A& x)
> ```

---

> The only connection between them is that in B I use an operator that converts B to A

... and the second connection between them is that in `B`, you use a constructor that converts `A` to `B`.

> You are right that this a conversion cunstroctor. But why this called when the assignement bar = foo takes place.

Because the given operand of the assignment has the type `A`, while the declared argument type is `const B&`.

In cases where the argument type does not match the declaration, the compiler checks whether there exists an *implicit conversion sequence* which could be used to convert the argument. As, `A` is implicitly convertible to `B`, such implicit conversion sequence exists and will be used.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a copy constructor that you have, it's a conversion constructor. The conversion constructor is called because you can turn a `A` into a `B`.

Do this:

```
explicit B(const A& x)
```

And now you will forbid the implicit conversion from `A` to `B`.

When you do:

```
bar = foo;
```

The compiler looks for sensible operations and allows for one conversion at most. It can use the copy assignment from `B`, and it knows it can create a `B` out of an `A` (because the constructor is not explicit), so it does this silently.

As @lubgr said, clang-tidy has a rule to check these and this is [part of the C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-explicit).

Comment: You are right that this a conversion cunstroctor. But why this called when the assignement  bar = foo takes place. This the point that I am msiing

Comment: Updated my answer with what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

You have an implicit constructor

```
B::B(const A&)
```

which performs the conversion that you don't want. You can change the signature to

```
explicit B(const A&);
```

to trigger a compilation error. Note that it's good practice to mark constructors with one argument `explicit` by default (there is a `clang-tidy` [check](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/google-explicit-constructor.html) for it, too), just to avoid such conversions by accident (IMHO, it would even be better if constructors that can be constructed with a single argument would be `explicit` by default with the ability to make the implicit).